# Import Android project not select 'copy project into workspace' error

Tags: android, eclipse, bitbucket

I have a problem with importing Android project to Eclipse in three scenario:

1. I have clone my Android project from Bitbucket and synchonized with Eclipse workspace successfully! But the project raise many error.
2. Then I remove my project and using import function in android (File>import project). I import the project from repo and also check to 'copy project into workspace', awesome! the project work perfectly.
3. Then I testing again. I also use import function and not check on 'copy project into workspace', oh no, the project keep the error like scenario 1.

Answer (score 0):

We've always had this issue - however, we face it in P4 SCM.

I guess the problem would be the same, anyway - your project may not be detected as an Android project.

First create a new Android Project. Now, go to Navigator in Eclipse (`Window -> Show View -> Navigator`) and open `.project` file - copy it's contents and paste in your (imported) project's `.project` file. This should fix it.

Make sure to make the required changes (the project name is the only change we usually make) after copying.

Comment: It's still not work. I found the error are: in eclipse workspace had a project named `appcompat_v7` with library named `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in the folder `Android Private Libraries`. In my project (imported) references to that library and the project imported not content that library. Im a newbie to android, so help me solve it. Thanks

Comment: It looks like Android Support Libraries are not available. Can you try to follow the steps found in the [Android Developer site here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) and check if that works? Remember to restart eclipse (or clean the projects) after doing this.